# Probability that none of $n$ units fail, given the probability of each failing

Tags: probability

The question says

In a letter to the editor that appeared in the February 23, 1987, of U.S. News and World Report, a reader discussed the issue of space shuttle safety. Each "critically 1" item is required to have 99.99% reliability according to nasa standards, meaning that the probability of failure for such an item is .0001. Mission 25 had 748 "critically 1" items. Determine the probability that none of the "critically 1" items would fail.

My thoughts were that if we call $S_i$   the event that the i th   "critically 1" item would succeed, then we want P($s_1$   and $s_2$   and .... and $s_{748}$  )

However, I am reading an introductory statistics book and I am on the chapter on the multiplication rule and independence, so my method looks convoluted and unworkable at my current level. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: So assuming (not necessarily reasonably) independence, we get $(0.9999)^{748}$.

Comment: "Criticality", perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming independence, we can use the multiplication rule to get:

$P(S_1 \ \text{AND} \ S_2 \ \text{AND} \cdots \ \text{AND} \ S_{748}) = P(S_1)P(S_2)\cdots P(S_{748}) = p^{748}$,

where $p$ is the probability that a "critically 1" item does not fail. This isn't hard to calculate.